# Error:(37, 41) error: package com.example.android.common.logger does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-places-api, importerror

I'm trying to implement the google place picker in my app and I got following errors. How do I resolve them? I think the right google place picker and logger library files are not imported. Help would be much appreciated thanks!

```
C:\Users\ACEM\Downloads\Compressed\MRestro4_2\MRestro4\app\src\main\java\com\golo\acer\mrestro4\android\common\activities\SampleActivityBase.java
Error:(22, 41) error: package com.example.android.common.logger does not exist
Error:(23, 41) error: package com.example.android.common.logger does not exist
Error:(47, 9) error: cannot find symbol class LogWrapper
Error:(47, 37) error: cannot find symbol class LogWrapper
Error:(48, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
Error:(50, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
C:\Users\ACEM\Downloads\Compressed\MRestro4_2\MRestro4\app\src\main\java\com\golo\acer\mrestro4\google\playservices\placepicker\cardstream\CardStreamFragment.java
Error:(30, 51) error: package com.example.google.playservices.placepicker does not exist
Error:(59, 39) error: package R does not exist
Error:(60, 63) error: package R does not exist
C:\Users\ACEM\Downloads\Compressed\MRestro4_2\MRestro4\app\src\main\java\com\golo\acer\mrestro4\google\playservices\placepicker\cardstream\CardStreamLinearLayout.java
Error:(37, 41) error: package com.example.android.common.logger does not exist
Error:(38, 51) error: package com.example.google.playservices.placepicker does not exist
Error:(140, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
Error:(147, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
Error:(149, 54) error: package R does not exist
Error:(165, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
Error:(173, 49) error: package R does not exist
Error:(181, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
Error:(233, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
Error:(400, 22) error: package R does not exist
Error:(403, 43) error: package R does not exist
Error:(416, 52) error: package R does not exist
Error:(423, 21) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
C:\Users\ACEM\Downloads\Compressed\MRestro4_2\MRestro4\app\src\main\java\com\golo\acer\mrestro4\google\playservices\placepicker\PlacePickerFragment.java
Error:(30, 46) error: package com.google.android.gms.location.places does not exist
Error:(31, 49) error: package com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui does not exist
Error:(33, 62) error: package com.example.google.playservices.placepicker.cardstream does not exist
Error:(34, 62) error: package com.example.google.playservices.placepicker.cardstream does not exist
Error:(35, 62) error: package com.example.google.playservices.placepicker.cardstream does not exist
Error:(36, 62) error: package com.example.google.playservices.placepicker.cardstream does not exist
Error:(102, 28) error: package PlacePicker does not exist
Error:(102, 74) error: package PlacePicker does not exist
Error:(153, 23) error: cannot find symbol class Place
Error:(153, 37) error: cannot find symbol variable PlacePicker
Error:(162, 38) error: cannot find symbol variable PlacePicker
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 6.081 secs
Information:34 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

***UPDATED:***

**My Project Gradle code:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**My Module Gradle code:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.golo.acer.mrestro4"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
}
```

**MORE ERRORS:**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics900Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl900Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase900Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement900Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation900Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps900Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks900Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics900Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl900Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon900Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore900Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid900Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\ACEM\Downloads\Compressed\MRestro4_2\MRestro4\app\google-services.json
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
C:\Users\ACEM\Downloads\Compressed\MRestro4_2\MRestro4\app\src\main\java\com\golo\acer\mrestro4\google\playservices\placepicker\PlacePickerFragment.java
Error:(33, 62) error: package com.example.google.playservices.placepicker.cardstream does not exist
Error:(34, 62) error: package com.example.google.playservices.placepicker.cardstream does not exist
Error:(35, 62) error: package com.example.google.playservices.placepicker.cardstream does not exist
Error:(36, 62) error: package com.example.google.playservices.placepicker.cardstream does not exist
C:\Users\ACEM\Downloads\Compressed\MRestro4_2\MRestro4\app\src\main\java\com\golo\acer\mrestro4\android\common\activities\SampleActivityBase.java
Error:(22, 41) error: package com.example.android.common.logger does not exist
Error:(23, 41) error: package com.example.android.common.logger does not exist
Error:(47, 9) error: cannot find symbol class LogWrapper
Error:(47, 37) error: cannot find symbol class LogWrapper
Error:(48, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
Error:(50, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
C:\Users\ACEM\Downloads\Compressed\MRestro4_2\MRestro4\app\src\main\java\com\golo\acer\mrestro4\google\playservices\placepicker\cardstream\CardStreamFragment.java
Error:(30, 51) error: package com.example.google.playservices.placepicker does not exist
Error:(59, 39) error: package R does not exist
Error:(60, 63) error: package R does not exist
C:\Users\ACEM\Downloads\Compressed\MRestro4_2\MRestro4\app\src\main\java\com\golo\acer\mrestro4\google\playservices\placepicker\cardstream\CardStreamLinearLayout.java
Error:(37, 41) error: package com.example.android.common.logger does not exist
Error:(38, 51) error: package com.example.google.playservices.placepicker does not exist
Error:(140, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
Error:(147, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
Error:(149, 54) error: package R does not exist
Error:(165, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
Error:(173, 49) error: package R does not exist
Error:(181, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
Error:(233, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
Error:(400, 22) error: package R does not exist
Error:(403, 43) error: package R does not exist
Error:(416, 52) error: package R does not exist
Error:(423, 21) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 19.609 secs
Information:27 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

**Fragment Errors:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

App build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.golo.acer.mrestro4"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I did and it asked to upgrade gradle and after upgrading I'm getting the following error:  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Comment: change your google services version to above version.

Comment: Still I get the same error and the services-analytics one is underlined red!

Comment: Now I'm getting even more errors..updated above. What is happening? :(

Comment: It is above in "More Error"

Comment: are you sure you use 8.4.0 version for google services in your gradle.

Comment: I had changed it to 9.0.0 and that solved previous errors, I change it to 8.4.0 and it shows this: Error:(32, 0) Version: 8.4.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\ACEM\Downloads\Compressed\MRestro4_2\MRestro4\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: answer updated it's working for me without any error.

Comment: I guess that solved the play services error but I get new errors like in the pictures above. Why is it not importing those classes?

Comment: because import path is wrong simply remove imports and reimport using Alt+Enter